# Warning in MySQL log file

Tags: mysql, triggers, warnings

I'm getting the following warning in my error log on MySQL 5.5.27.   Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

> [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since 
>   BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statement is unsafe because it invokes a trigger or a stored function that inserts into an AUTO_INCREMENT column. Inserted values cannot be logged correctly. Statement: Insert Into Alt_Address (`AddressType`,`EntityNo`,`SeqNo`,`Name`,`Address1`,`Address2`,`City`,`State`,`PostCode`,`Contact`,`PhoneNo`,`PhoneExtension`,`FaxNo`,`SPLC_Code`,`DateLastChange`,`ExportAddress1`,`ExportAddress2`,`ExportAddress3`,`ExportAddress4`,`ExportAddress5`,`ExportPhoneNo`,`ExportInspectionReqd`,`JV_Branch`,`JV_Yard`,`JV_Supplier`,`JV_MaterialPrefix`,`EDIBuilt`,`ExcludeAutoBuild`,`LastUpdatedBy`,`LastUpdatedProgramNo`)

Comment: Seems clear enough. there's a trigger that's trying to mess around with an auto_increment field.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* not be anything to worry about. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64758

Is the trigger working?

Comment: Yes.  I was wondering if it telling me that I won't be able to use my binlog to restore because the autoincrement numbers won't be correct?